# how to handle CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation in classic/nonretina display

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

In one of the pages of my application there are three views. In each view there are 4 to 5 controls and all three views are in a `UIScrollView`.
At one point I am hiding the middle view and translating `lastview` view in place of the middle view. The code is as follows:

```
lastview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -270);
```

The problem is that it is working on the retina display but not in the non-retina display; for example the 3GS display.